# How to load url in webview in background while splashscreen is showing?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is my splashscreen activity.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
  private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=10000;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Timer r=new Timer();
    new Handler().postDelayed(r,SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
  }

  class Timer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

  }
}
```

This is my MainActivity. This activity Should be performed in background while splashscreen is on the front. Is it advisable to use AsyncTask. How to do that?

If not AsyncActivity, What can I use?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private WebView webview;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            if(url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
                startActivity(intent); 
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    }
            );
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
  }
    //this is to go back to previous pages if exists
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack()){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

If possible can I set the time for the splashscreen to view as long as the url is loaded without giving time?

The second attempt

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webview;
private boolean isSplashOn = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_splash);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            if(url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent); 
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(isSplashOn) { 
                webview.setBackgroundDrawable(null);             
                webview.setBackgroundColor(0);

                isSplashOn = false;
            }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
            );
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack()){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Guys. Still the problem is't solved. Need some help

Comment: Combine both activities. Show the splash screen first and load the webview on background. Initially keep the web view as hidden. After the timeout is done show the webview. (Its just a hack)

Comment: @RaviGadipudi can you explain me in elaborated way. I'm just a beginner. So ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without AsyncTask and you can hide the splash screen when the page loaded without a timer.

**WebViewClient** class has a method `onPageFinished()` which will be called once the page has been loaded. You can make use of it.

In you project folder, place your splash screen images with name 'splash_screen.png' (or whatever name you want. If you want to use a different name then change this line `webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_screen);` to map to your splash screen image file) under **res/drawable-xxx** with corresponding resolutions.

For Eg:
I followed these resolutions for my app's splash screen.

hdpi - 400x800
ldpi - 240x320
mdpi - 320x480
xdpi - 640x960

And try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Activity activity = this;

    private WebView webView;

    private boolean isSplashOn = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_screen);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            if(url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(!isSplashOn) {               
                webView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                webView.setBackgroundColor(0);

                isSplashOn = true;
            }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();

                return true;
            }else {
                activity.finish();
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

By the way i found the issue with your code. You are trying to set the splash screen to the webview before instantiating it.

Change your code from this:

```
webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_splash);

webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.output);
```

to this:

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.output);

webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activity_splash);
```

Comment: Its not working like this. App is crashing when I use this kind of code. Okay. Now if I want to do it with AsyncTask, how should I do this?

Comment: I posted it in the question with the second attempt @kesavan

Comment: @Krishna, In your second code snippet, i could not able to see any code that is using a splash screen. By the way are you creating a separate activity for the splash screen?

Comment: No. I removed the splash.java Activity from manifest. No part of the program is pointing to Splash.class When I tried your code,

Comment: You have to place the splash screen image on the res/drawable-xxxx folders with the name splash_screen. Refer here for various sizes [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90825/discussion-between-krishna-and-kesavan).

Comment: @Krishna I've edited the answer. Find fix for your bug under edit part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the simple trick - 
I was showing a loading spinner till the page was being loaded in background.
Thus I had used two web views.
In your case, you can use ImageView or any other view.

**XML** file will like this -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

//Actual webview
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/actual_webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

//Any view you want to show while webpage is loading
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, in your **JAVA** file-

```
//initially, make actual_webview invisible
        actual_webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Also, in

```
     @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

// make spinner_webview invisible
    spinner_webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// make actual_webview visible
    actual_webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Also,

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)
onPageStarted(...)
onPageFinished(...)
```

In all these methods, you get the URL and can check which URL is being loaded or finished loading.
According to the URL you can decide whether to show / hide the splash screen.

Comment: sorry for that man. I already got the solution.got the solution from another post.  so forgot to make it solved. anyways. solution is in a part of your answer. Thank you for that.

Comment: Its ok man..ultimately its good that you found the answer..!!

Comment: If you are good with web applications in java please come here. the give answer there helped me. But still there are problems with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968006/how-to-update-the-location-based-on-the-latlong-variables-in-google-maps-on-web

Comment: I cannot answer there as the question has been put on hold. I have done the same thing in my android app, but cannot share the logic in this comment because of character limit.

Comment: So. If you can please start a chat room and share some code. I'll try to implement it in my way. Please

Comment: Sorry but you will have to start it as i do not have required privileges.

Comment: I'll try to start. Please wait

Comment: [Try to come here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91839/krishna-dsd-chat-room)

Answer (score 2):

Why does the splash has to be an activity?

You can make it a full screen ImageView in the bottom of your layout and hide it using a handler:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isDestroyed())
                return;
            mSplashView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    },2000);
```