# How to update the location based on the latlong variables in google maps on web page?

Tags: java, web-services, google-maps, servlets, web-applications

I'm pretty new to web applications. I built an android application which will send latlong coordinates of the mobile user every second.Now I want to build a web application which will present Google Map. It should receive the latlong coordinates every second from the android device and should move the location marker on the map accordingly. what should I use in order to make it happen? How should I do it?
I want to use java here.

Comment: This is not a search engine.. show some efforts first

Comment: @sunil If I know what to use I can work upon it. Anyways thanks for so kind suggestion.

Comment: Ok I will add some description in answer follow it

Comment: @sunil Please. I will work on it if I know where to start. And now really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your android device must send message to your application including lat & lng.. by means of any messaging technology.
2. Your web app should listen to those message events and receive location from msg.
3. You should use any scripting language with HTML and can load google map in your page and according to received location from message you can plot marker on map which will display current location of device. Then to update location you can change that marker's position..

This is brief description of your problem, how to load map in HTML and how to place marker ..you can get this stuff on google

Comment: I'm planning to use web service for passing latlong variables. Web service will receive coordinates and will pass the values to the javascript variables to place the marker on map. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes that is the correct way